# Send data to Realm object server from app

Tags: android, realm

I am creating an Android application in which I am using the Realm database to store data, and I am using the Realm object server to login and register user. I am able to log a user in using `SyncUser` and I am able to see that my login user has been stored in the Realm object server.

But now I have additional fields that I want to store - for instance, mail and age. I know how I'd store it in a different database but I don't know how to do this in Realm.

Comment: Open the Realm with SyncConfiguration then write the RealmObject into it

Comment: Yes,this is i am asking.How to open and write and what to write?

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#opening-a-synchronized-realm

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about storing metadata about a user. That is not supported yet, but will be added soon. You can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4645. For now the workaround would be to save them in your own custom User Object.